# Superscript into sprintf

Tags: r, plot, formatting

I'd like to introduce a superscript into 'sprintf'. I've tried different options but I'm stuck with this. Any help greatly appreciated!

Input:

```
sprintf("r = %s & %s = %s%%", fit1.r, "r"[2], fit1.r2pp)
```

Output:

```
## [1] "r = 0.95 & NA = 90%"
```

- I'd like the 'NA' to be r elevated to 2 (r^2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for a `plot`

```
fit1.r <- 0.95
fit1.r2pp <- 90
plot(1,1, main=bquote('r =' ~.(fit1.r)~'& r'^2~'='~.(fit1.r2pp)*'%'))
```

[image]